# how do i get two variables to divide in ruby?

Tags: ruby, variables, math

I have my variables, `height` and `distance`. They are inputted by the user. I want to divide them and turn the result into a new variable, `ratio`.

```
print "How high are you?"
height = gets.chomp
print "How far are you from the landing strip?"
distance = gets.chomp
ratio = distance.to_f / height
```

when I try and run this, it just tells me

```
`/': String can't be coerced into Float (TypeError)
```

Any help?

Comment: When debugging a problem IRB is your best friend. Dropping into IRB and typing `gets.chomp.class` would have answered the question and allowed you to figure out the problem.

Comment: In your question you reference gets.chomp without showing what gets is.

Comment: @jBeas, `gets.chomp` in this is used to turn user input into a variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure that both `distance` and `height` are an Integer or Float before the calculation.

I would convert the variables to Floats immediately after the inputs using `gets.to_f` (don't need `.chomp` as `to_f` would also remove the newline):

```
print "How high are you?"
height = gets.to_f
print "How far are you from the landing strip?"
distance = gets.to_f
ratio = distance / height
```

Answer (score 4):

You are getting this error because height is still a string. This means that you are dividing a float (distance.to_f) by a string (height).

To fix it, convert height into a number with to_f:

```
`ratio = distance.to_f / height.to_f`
```

Also it would be good practice to check that the entered values actually are numbers or not. By default a non-numeric string (a string with no numbers in it) will be converted to zero if you call to_f or to_i on it.

Comment: If by "non-numeric string" (no string is numeric) you mean strings that are not representations of numbers, your last sentence is not correct, for `"12.3cat".to_i #=> 12` and `"12.3cat".to_f #=> 12.3`.

Comment: Thanks for the catch Cary. I modified it to specify that I was referring to strings which contain no numbers such as "Hi" or "Foo".